# Spark having issue reading teradata table which have display names for the table columns

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark, teradata

I am trying to read from Teradata table:

```
val df = spark.read.format("jdbc")
      .option("driver", "com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver")
      .option("url", "jdbc:teradata://abc.xyz.com/database=db_name")
      .option("dbtable", "table_name")
      .option("user", "user_name")
      .option("password", "password")
      .load()
```

I am getting error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: [Teradata Database] [TeraJDBC 16.20.00.13] [Error 5628] [SQLState HY000] Column Data Rate not found in db_name.table_name.
```

In Teradata schema, column is defined like:

```
data_rate DECIMAL(18,0) FORMAT '-(18)9' TITLE 'Data Rate',
```

Please let me know how to solve this issue. Can anything be done on Spark side to solve this..?

Thanks

Comment: Try appending the `,column_name=on` option to the url.

Comment: Do you need to use the column title, as opposed to the column name? As far as I know, titles can use any characters, which may or may not be allowed in Spark or other technologies. As a quick example, Parquet objects can't include spaces.

Comment: @Andrew These titles are already present in the Teradata tables since long and I can't change it. The only thing I can try is in Spark code.

Comment: appending column_name=on has worked. it is mentioned in teradata docs..
https://teradata-docs.s3.amazonaws.com/doc/connectivity/jdbc/reference/current/jdbcug_chapter_2.html